# How to use includes on rails 5.0 active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm tryin to get all data including has_many assosoation :

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
has_many :order_details

class OrderDetail < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :order
```

Then retrive data using :

```
@orders = Order.includes(:order_details)
```

But output it's only orders data :

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  customer_id: 4,
  code: "c2306df9",
  date: "2016-09-18T12:13:00.000Z",
  downpayment: 500000,
  amount: 3000000,
  created_at: "2016-11-06T07:44:07.000Z",
  updated_at: "2016-11-06T07:44:09.000Z"
 }
]
```

My Expect is data order and order details merged. Is there any issue about includes on Rails 5.0 or may there is any another way ?

May Sameone can help. Thanks

Comment: Your expectations is not correct. If you run `@orders.map { |x| x.order_details }` you will see order details.

Answer (score 1):

`includes` is a way to tell Rails to eager load associated records to avoid N+1 queries.

It does not necessarily mean that Rails performs a `JOIN` query nor that Rails performs only one query. Often Rails does two queries - one for the original request and another to load all associated records at once. Rails makes the decision which strategy to use depending on the type of the relation and the original query parameters.

Even if Rails makes a `JOIN` and loads all records in one query, the output would still not include the association. The format of the output depends on how the output serializer is configured and Rails doesn't include associated records into the output per default.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  So the best way is using query string ? correct me please.

Comment: `includes` is a powerful method to avoid `N+1` queries. But I cannot tell you the best way to do something, because you actually never told us what you try to achieve. You only wrote about that `includes` doesn't do what you were thinking it should do. Can you please explain what you try to achieve and what you mean by *query string*?

Comment: Thanks for your response Spicker. Issue solved. thanks for your hand.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, what you're trying to achieve is:

```
OrderDetail.joins(:order).map do |order_detail|
  [order_detail.order.attributes, order_detail.attributes]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response David